# How to send text to the Password field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Selenium with Chromedriver Python: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cs s selector","selector":"[id="password"]"}

I edited the question to says, it works well when using the chrome browser, but the same code fails in --headless mode (which is what I want to use)

I have been scratching my head over the past week with this issue:
Chromedriver cannot find the *presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))*, although it is clearly there as seen in the screenshot.
It finds the username by the same By.ID and inputs it correctly, but when it gets to thew password, it fails.

[****@mtlab-auto tmp]$ google-chrome --version

Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106

headless chrome=83.0.4103.106

Python 3.8.0 (default, May  7 2020, 02:49:39)

```
    ########### Chrome option  ###############
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')
chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
chromeOptions.add_argument('start-maximized')
chromeOptions.add_argument('disable-infobars')

prefs = {'download.default_directory' : f'{temp_folder}'}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)

# capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
# capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True 
# capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

############# Set chrome proxy ###########
Chrome_Proxy = 'http://135.28.13.11:8888'
#Chrome_Proxy = 'http://autoproxy.sbc.com/autoproxy.cgi'
chromeOptions.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % Chrome_Proxy)

############### Enable chrome browser wedriver ##############
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/dev/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions,\
service_args = [f'--log-path={chromeDriver_log}'])

# browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/dev/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions,\
# desired_capabilities = capabilities, service_args = [f'--log-path={chromeDriver_log}'])

############## Set the timeout values ###############
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
#browser.set_page_load_timeout(15)
#browser.implicitly_wait(40)
element_timeout = 30
print()
print(Fore.BLUE + '>>> Accessing Cisco Cloud...')

browser.get(r'https://slexui.cloudapps.cisco.com/SWIFT/LicensingUI/Quickstart')

time.sleep(20)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/main-page.png')

try:
    element_login = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-button'))
    WebDriverWait(browser, element_timeout).until(element_login)

except TimeoutException:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Fail to load login page')
    print('RC=101,"Error: Failed to load Cisco Website"')
    browser.close()
    quit()

print()
print(browser.title)
print()

######### Login to cisco cloud account ###########
print(Fore.BLUE + ' >>> Login to Cisco Cloud')

######################## Username ##################
try:
    element_username = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'userInput'))
    WebDriverWait(browser, element_timeout).until(element_username).send_keys(f'{cisco_userid}')

except TimeoutException:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Fail to load login page')
    print('RC=101,"Error: Failed to login to Cisco Website"')
    browser.close()
    quit()

time.sleep(2)
#browser.find_element_by_id('userInput').send_keys(f'{cisco_userid}')
print('>>>> Username input')
browser.find_element_by_id('login-button').click()

time.sleep(20)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('/tmp/password.png')

###################### Password ##################
try:
    element_password = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))
    WebDriverWait(browser, element_timeout).until(element_password).send_keys(f'{cisco_password}')

except TimeoutException:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Timed out waiting for page to load')
    print('RC=101,"Error: Failed to login to Cisco Website"')
    browser.close()
    quit()

time.sleep(5)
#browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(f'{cisco_password}')
print('>>>> Password input')
browser.find_element_by_id('kc-login').click()

############# Check if we are logged in #############
```

And here is the log: it finds my username and puts in the correct username, but fails at the password field. I took a screenshot right after I enter my username, and you can clearly see the password field and nothing is found by chromedriver

```
[1592922143.110][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND Navigate {
   "url": "https://slexui.cloudapps.cisco.com/SWIFT/LicensingUI/Quickstart"
}
[1592922143.110][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922143.111][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922168.003][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922243.956][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922243.956][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE Navigate
[1592922263.980][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND Screenshot {

}
[1592922263.980][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922263.982][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.304][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.305][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.305][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE Screenshot "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6Q
AAIABJREFUeJzs3XecnWWZN/DfmTnTMsmkzARCEpDQErq0QABBREEhSHEtKJaAq7irK7Iq+y7i6loWQRfbWt5XkSILWEFBikgRCIjSCaFICAgJ6clMMpPp7x+DE0ISQpKBgYfv9..."
[1592922264.309][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[id=\"login-button\"]"
}
[1592922264.309][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.310][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.329][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.330][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.330][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement {
   "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "0db6e420-49df-46ab-9939-b2f471f9d919"
}
[1592922264.331][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND GetTitle {

}
[1592922264.331][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.332][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.335][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.336][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.336][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE GetTitle "Cisco.com Login Page"
[1592922264.337][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[id=\"userInput\"]"
}
[1592922264.337][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.338][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.355][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.356][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.356][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement {
   "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "72de3929-e23d-436c-ab22-adb6e79109bd"
}
[1592922264.357][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND TypeElement {
   "id": "72de3929-e23d-436c-ab22-adb6e79109bd",
   "text": "an144a001",
   "value": [ "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "0", "0", "1" ]
}
[1592922264.357][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.358][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.496][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922264.497][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922264.497][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE TypeElement
[1592922266.502][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[id=\"login-button\"]"
}
[1592922266.502][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922266.504][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922266.517][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922266.518][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922266.518][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement {
   "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "0db6e420-49df-46ab-9939-b2f471f9d919"
}
[1592922266.521][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND ClickElement {
   "id": "0db6e420-49df-46ab-9939-b2f471f9d919"
}
[1592922266.521][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922266.522][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922266.622][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922266.624][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922266.624][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE ClickElement
[1592922286.634][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND Screenshot {

}
[1592922286.634][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922286.636][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.079][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922287.080][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.080][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE Screenshot "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6Q
AAIABJREFUeJzs3XmYnFWdL/BvVVd3p7uTzk72QAiBQFiCsqNsAVzhDoIoijqIo86AOnp1HK+z4DIzOug4V8dt0FHwKqCAsiggKosgEER22RMEAiEL2Tvpte4fkQ6dfemk4OXze..."
[1592922287.087][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[name=\"password\"]"
}
[1592922287.087][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922287.088][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.109][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922287.110][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.110][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cs
s selector","selector":"[name="password"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.106)
[1592922287.614][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[name=\"password\"]"
}
[1592922287.614][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922287.615][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.628][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922287.629][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922287.629][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cs
s selector","selector":"[name="password"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.106)
[1592922288.132][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[name=\"password\"]"
}
[1592922288.132][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922288.133][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922288.145][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922288.146][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922288.146][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cs
s selector","selector":"[name="password"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.106)
[1592922288.649][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[name=\"password\"]"
}
[1592922288.649][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922288.650][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922288.662][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1592922288.663][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1592922288.663][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cs
s selector","selector":"[name="password"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.106)
[1592922289.166][INFO]: [cb94f02b714bfe0ce21b3dac35546605] COMMAND FindElement {
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "[name=\"password\"]"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you don't use proxy?

Comment: I have to use proxy to access the internet

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* within the *Password* field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://slexui.cloudapps.cisco.com/SWIFT/LicensingUI/Quickstart')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#userInput"))).send_keys("an144a001")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#login-button").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password"))).send_keys("Checksum321")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://slexui.cloudapps.cisco.com/SWIFT/LicensingUI/Quickstart')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='userInput']"))).send_keys("an144a001")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login-button']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']"))).send_keys("Checksum321")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: identity_cisco]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My original post and your answer work well when using the chrome browser, but fails in --headless mode. I am using this in headless mode. Even with your proposed answer, it fails in headless mode. It finds the username, but fails to find the password field when using either ID, XPATH, or CSS

Answer (score 0):

Some problems i was facing in your some situation:

- The html of the page had been loading differently using the headless mode and it didn't find some elements. Try using it commenting headless mode.
- Try finding it in a different way, i.e. using find_element_by_xpath or class_name.
- Try using interactive console, get the full path of the password element in the browser windows loaded by selenium and execute the command `find_element_by_xpath(full_path). It should work, if not try interactivly all methods and then change accordingly in your code.

Hope to be usefull

Comment: Thank you! I think you are in the right path. Mine worked well when using the chrome browser, but it fails in headless mode. I need to use this in headless mode within a script. In headless mode, I tried ID, XPATH, adding long wait time, it finds the username correctly, but always fails to find the password field. You can see in the screenshot I posted, the password field is visible, but I get a "RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element:". I have not tried the (full_xpath) yet, but will see if it makes any difference.

Comment: What about pressing TAB after inserting the username?
`from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import Keys`

`actions = ActionChains(browser) `
`actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)`
`actions.perform()`
Then you should be in the password field and be able to send the password key.

Comment: That would not work, since the "username" and "password" are on different pages. First you are presented with a screen to enter just your username, then you click next where it asks for the password. Just like signing into google.